# undefined error in v-show vue

Tags: vue-component, vue.js

In my Vue 2.0 .vue component file, I've got two 'conditions' and based on when they become true, I show them to the user. I have a button to toggle

```
<tr v-show="showMonth" v-for="player in players">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ player.stats.month.goals }}</td>
  <td>{{ player.stats.month.assists }}</td>
  <td>{{ player.stats.month.played }}</td>
</tr>
<tr v-show="showYear" v-for="player in players">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ player.stats.year.goals }}</td>
  <td>{{ player.stats.year.assists }}</td>
  <td>{{ player.stats.year.played }}</td>
</tr>
```

Keep in mind that each `<tr>...</tr>` will be populated(get data from api) only when a use 'toggles' the showYear or showMonth. Now the problem arises when showYear is toggled then `player.stats.month` which is required in the showMonth `<tr>...</tr>` throws the error "player.stats.month is undefined". Is there anyway I can get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `v-show` with `v-if` and it will work as it will render only when it should.
`v-show` changes only visibility, when `v-if` putting it into DOM only when true.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use v-if thinking that it would only load once. This is what I need!